# confusion regarding the stars in sky

Tags: stars

Although directly looking at sun with naked eye is very risky health wise but I heard from someone that the sun that we see is what actually it looked like 8 minutes ago as light takes 8 minutes to travel from sun to earth. Since sun is a star and we can carry on this concept to other stars and we can say that some of the stars that we see in night sky, they may be at distance of billion of light years ago from us

Comment: The stars we see are not a billion light years away, but mostly dozens or hundreds of light years away ([relevant XKCD](https://xkcd.com/1342/)).

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Answer to the probable follow up question of 'how do we know how far away they are' https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_distance_ladder#

Comment: Even if edited does not seem on topic here.

Answer (score 3):

Light travels at 300 000km/s meaning that everything you see is actually how it looked in the past. So at that speed, it takes sun light 8 minutes to travel from the sun to the Earth. That is why the light from the Sun is actually the light emitted from the sun 8 min ago.

To measure the distance a star is, we use the measurement light year. That is the distance light travels in a year. A human on earth would see a star 10 lights years away as it was 10 years ago since it takes 10 years for the light to travel from that star to us.

This also means that we see objects which are billions of lights years away how they were billions of years ago. This is actually very practical because we can figure out how things were in the past. In other words, looking at very far objects is like looking in the past.

As Gerrit mentioned in his comment, most stars we see in the sky are actually quite close. To see things millions of years in the past, we need to use telescopes such as the JWST or Hubble

Comment: We don't with the naked eye see objects which are billions of light years away.

Comment: @gerrit that is correct. We use telescopes like the Hubble or JWST. I added it to my answer now

Comment: Andromeda galaxy is 2.5 million light years away and is (just barely) discernable to the unaided eye. I think that's likely the distance limit.

Comment: What's really amazing is that not only are we literally looking into the past, we are looking various amounts of time into the past simultaneously. For example if you look at the Orion constellation, you are looking at Betelgeuse as it existed about 550 years ago, and simultaneously looking at Rigel as it existed over 850 years ago. And what we often forget is that the "real" sky is different than what we see, for example Polaris in reality is no longer due north, we see it where it was 300 years ago. And Betelgeuse may not even be there anymore considering its recent shenanigans.

Comment: Somewhat ironically, it's hard to measure the distance to Betelgeuse because it's so big & bright. See https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/36365/16685